# Swift 4 - Setting a minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, target, minimum

The current deployment target is 11.0 which is fine.
However, I would like to know how I would set a minimum of 8.0?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the deployment target in your project's target's general settings.

[image: Adjust Deployment target]

You can read more about this in Apple documentation ["Setting Deployment Target"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW21).