# How to Build an Application compatible with older MacOS with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, build, version

I just installed the latest version of Xcode (10.1) on MacOS 10.14 (Mojave).
I can build my application and it runs fine on my Mac or similar system.

However, I want to share this application with someone using MacOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and it fails to launch, asking for a minimum requirement of MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra).

My application is only very simple, can't I compile it to be compatible with older MacOS ?

---

After some research, I did download MacOSX10.11.sdk
(from https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases/).
I did decompress it, and drag it into:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`
(This folder originally contains only "MacOSX.sdk" and a link pointing to it, named "MacOSX10.14.sdk")

[image: MacOS SDK folder in Xcode]

I also noticed the value of the string "MinimumSDKVersion" from the file `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Info.plist` is equal to "10.11", which sounds good in my case.

I read on some forums adding additional SDK versions into Xcode is not supported. And by the way, I cannot see any menu from Xcode to specify my target build (neither in Xcode Preferences, nor in the project settings (see picture below).

[image]

Where can I tell Xcode to use, let's say "MacOSX10.11.sdk" over "MacOSX10.14.sdk"?

And, is there a better way?

Or, do I have to install an old version of MacOS on a different partition, with an old version of Xcode (which would be a pain)?

Comment: You should compile against the latest SDK, and set the "Minimum Deployment Target" to the earliest macOS version you wish to support (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467255/233944). Be careful to only use APIs that are available on the system your app is running on.

Comment: @TheNextman Thank you, that's exactly the option I was looking for. So I wasn't looking at the right place. I was imagining complicated ways, but the solution was only very simple. If you wrote your comment as an answer, I would accept it greatly. The SO ticket you pointed illustrates perfectly where the option lies. I didn't find it because I didn't think of such keywords as "deployment target swift". Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this still works on Mojave, but there is a project called XcodeLegacy which is created specifically with this intention in mind:
https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the menu, you can find it at: Xcode -> Select File -> Project/Workspace Setting

[Open Workspace Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwAoH.png)

Works on Xcode 13, I'm a bit late to the party but just had the very same question.